# Blob file download problem

Tags: php, database, uploads

I'm currently trying to download a blob archive file saved in the database

```
$fid = $_GET['fid'];

$sel = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE id = $fid" );
foreach( $sel as $head )
{
    $name = $head->name;
    $type = $head->type;
    $size = $head->size;
    $content = $head->content;

    header("Content-length: $size");
    header("Content-type: $type");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
    echo $content;
    exit;
}
```

every time I redirect to `/download?id=` with int value assigned to `id` it loads the file. However, instead of the browser prompting for file download location, the page reads the binary contents of the blob and displays it all as a string.

any other way of downloading a blob on wordpress?

Comment: When/where do you do this? What action is this hooked to?

Answer (score 2):

There are some security issues. 
Please sanitize your input because someone can download from Your database something different than archive, or simply drop Your database.

`$fid = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['fid'] );`

Comment: thanks for the reminder! but no worries I review my codes multiple times for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

Use the following content-type header in your code:

```
header( "Content-type: application/octet-stream" );
```

If that doesn't work - we successfully do this and though it is unlikely, it may be related to the order of things. Try it in the following order:

```
Content-type
Content-disposition
Content-Transfer-Encoding
Content-Length
```

And as was mentioned in the other answer - always sanitize input before using it directly in database queries.

Edited: Also add to ensure there's no caching (taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485886/force-file-download-with-php-using-header))-

```
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
```

Edited: Wrap up the code into an function to run at 'init' so it's not output in the theme content.

```
add_action(
    'init',
    function () {
        global $wpdb;

        $fid = sanitize_text_field( $_GET[ 'fid' ] );

        $sel = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE id = $fid" );
        foreach ( $sel as $head ) {
            $name = empty( $head->name ) ? 'myfile.name' : $head->name;
            $size = empty( $head->size ) ? strlen( $head->content ) : $head->size;

            header( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );
            header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name" );
            header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary' );
            header( "Content-Length: $size" );
            header( 'Connection: Keep-Alive' );
            header( 'Expires: 0' );
            header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
            header( 'Pragma: public' );

            echo $head->content;

            exit();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: still didn't work.. [here's](https://imgur.com/a/TAQeV) the output

Comment: And you *replaced* your line `header( "Content-type:` with my one?

Comment: yep! already did

Comment: I added a couple of other headers you could add. Also, your server might be caching the response it sends out which means you always get the same response.  So to test, make sure you add a new random number to your testing query.  So, for example, you have  asdfasdf.com?fid=1&rand=123
Each time you test it, change your `rand` number parameter

Comment: made me think maybe it's the theme doing this? it's displaying the file contents rather than prompting for a save file location

Comment: That would make sense. You should wrap up this into a function and hook it into 'init', for example. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: unfortunately, not yet, I just started using WP. tho I've been learning along the way

Comment: I've added a more full code block that you should be able to just use as-is.  If it works, please indicate with a vote up. Thanks!

Comment: Did that do the job for you?

Comment: unfortunately not yet. I'm currently trying on making a function for this